# How to: Docker container running java jar connecting to host mysql server?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, ubuntu

I wrote a simple java program that should connect to the host machine running a MYSQL server and insert a record. The java progam is running inside a docker container with an ubuntu base image. At this point I have the jar working but can't connect to the host machine MYSQL server yet.

I've tried different mysql server installs and coppied from other dockerfiles in the hope to copy/past something together that works but it's getting messy and I don't know what parts are necessary anymore.

Java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class ConnectionTest {

    private Connection conn;

    ConnectionTest() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            test();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logError(e);
        }
    }

    private void logError(SQLException e) throws IOException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        String sStackTrace = sw.toString();

        File fout = new File("logs.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        bw.write(sStackTrace);

        bw.close();
    }

    private void test() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException { ;
        String hostname = "localhost";
        String dbName = "test";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":3306/" + dbName + "?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris", userName, password);

        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(Login, Password) values('test', 'test')");
        prep.execute();
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/java
COPY jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz /
RUN tar -zxf jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /root/java

RUN apt-get update
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /root/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java 100

ENV JAVA_HOME /root/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin
RUN export JAVA_HOME

RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server \
 && sed -i "s/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g" /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf \
 && mkdir /var/run/mysqld \
 && chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]

CMD ["mysqld_safe"]

EXPOSE 3306

COPY lib /root/test/lib
COPY entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entrypoint.sh:

```
chmod -R 777 /root/test

cd /root/test

java -cp "lib/*" -jar lib/DockerTest.jar

tail -f /dev/null
```

/root/test/lib contains both the mysql-connector-java.jar and the DockerTest.jar. If I run mysqld before the jar the server starts but the jar won't launch.

MYSQL status when the server is running:

```
$ winpty docker exec -it mysql_container service mysql status
 * /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 3 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 4  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 105  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 98  Queries per second avg: 1.333
```

Error when running just the jar:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at ConnectionTest.test(ConnectionTest.java:42)
        at ConnectionTest.<init>(ConnectionTest.java:13)
        at Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Can you `telnet localhost 3306` from a terminal? Are you sure MySQL is accepting connections?  What else have you done to troubleshoot?  We really can't help as we don't have access to your system, and StackOverflow is not set up to be a debug/troubleshooting hand-hold service.

Comment: The mysql server is accepting connections, the jar works fine running locally on the host machine. I know the jar works and I know the mysql server works on the docker container I just can't create the connection from docker -> host database. What other information would be helpful?

Comment: For starters, a detailed description of the network configurations on the two systems.  Clearly when running everything on one VM host it works, but when separating the application and the database it doesn't. That means there's a networking problem between the two systems, so that's the place to start looking.

Comment: Usually the advice is one process per container, see https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container. You need Docker Compose to connect the multiple containers easily.

Comment: My host machine is running xampp mysql server with everything on default settings 127.0.0.1:3306, the firewall is configured to allow all incoming connections on port 3306. My docker container has nothing setup for connections,I figured if something in the container sends something to 3306 and it is mapped to the host local 3306 port it would go right through but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Framework you can set the `spring.datasource.url` in `application.properties` to use `host.docker.internal:3306` if the MySQL is running on your local / host machine.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/<yourdatabase>
```